# Pythonで、型名のみ取得する方法

Tags: python

Pythonのtype関数を利用すると、以下のように、型名だけでなく不等号記号などがついて表記されます。

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame()
print(type(data))
```

実行した結果、"<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>"と表示されます。

また__name__プロパティでは、親の名前が取れないようです。

```
print(type(data).__name__)
```

実行した結果、"DataFrame"と表示されます。

不等号記号などを除外した、また親の名前を含めた、名前空間+クラス名を取得したいのですが、
よりよい方法はないでしょうか。
現在は、次のようにsplitで独自に切り取っています。
もっとシンプルな方法があれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
print(str(type(data)).split("'")[1]) # ←よりシンプルな方法ないでしょうか
```

実行した結果、"pandas.core.frame.DataFrame"と表示されます。（←期待する結果です。）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんな風にできます

```py
>>> cls = data.__class__
>>> '.'.join([cls.__module__, cls.__name__])
'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
```

Comment: できました。ありがとうございます。
この方法を利用させていただきます。

Comment: あるいはこんな風にも `f'{cls.__module__}.{cls.__name__}'`

Comment: ありがとうございます。
要素二個固定の連結なので、fストリングに置き換えて利用していました。
より分かりやすくなったと思っています。